# This is question about the integral solutions of 2 different quadratic equations(Question from INMO 1995)

Tags: number-theory, quadratics

Show that there are infinitely many pairs(a,b) of relatively prime integers (not necessarily positive) such that both quadratic equations x²+ax+b=0 and x²+2ax+b=0 have integer roots

I have no idea on how to solve the question.  The only thing I tried was trying to look at the discrimants of the equations which must be perfect squares for the roots to be integer. The discrimants are a²-4b=m² and 4a²-4b=n².. I got no further

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that for infinitely many pairs of $(a,b)$ for $x^2+ax+b=0$ and $x^2+2ax+b=0$ have integer roots.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156366/show-that-for-infinitely-many-pairs-of-a-b-for-x2axb-0-and-x22axb-0). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2Bax%2Bb%3D0%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2B2ax%2Bb%3D0%24&p=1).

Comment: @JohnOmielan please do you know hot get mathematics keyboard . I am new to mathematics on websites like this

Comment: I assume "mathematics keyboard" means the math typesetting used. It's MathJax (which is quite similar to $\LaTeX$). For details, see [Short and helpful advice on using MathJax on the site ...](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/602049) and [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/602049). For example, your first quadratic equation could be typed as `$x^2 + ax + b = 0$`, with this appearing as $x^2 + ax + b = 0$. Also FYI, details about using Approach0 are in this [answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/602049).